# Is there any risk of being published in the wrong genre?

Tags: publishing, genre

From [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/3319/16341):

> However, unless you're an established author, you don't have the luxury of declaring your work to be fantasy or science fiction like Fowler does; someone else has to do that for you. That means your editor, publisher, your readership, and/or your peers and critics must declare it fantasy to be so.

I know next to nothing about publishing. After reading this, I am worried about being published in the wrong genre (assuming I ever get published). In my particular case, I am worried about being published under "young adult romance" (rather than "young adult fantasy") since my two main characters are very close, and their relationship can be mistaken as a romance.

Romance is something I want to avoid entirely. Is being published in the wrong genre something I have to worry about, or am I just being paranoid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Romance" vs. "fantasy" are significantly different genres. You can absolutely have romance in a fantasy and fantasy in a romance, and you can absolutely write a romantic story in a fantasy setting without the book being a "romance." The differences are in the plot and characters.

While I'm not familiar with the subgenre of YA Romance vs. adult Romance, a "romance" book focuses on the relationship. It's the point of the story. Robert Gellis's *Fires of Winter* is a romance set in medieval England and Scotland. The story is about the two characters coming to fall in love. *Robin Hood* is set in medieval England and has romance in it, but it's an adventure story because the romance is not the main purpose of the tale.

If your story is not *about* the romance, it's unlikely to be classified there.

Answer (score 5):

Genre is a marketing tool. Publishers are marketers of books. That is why you seek out a publisher rather than publishing yourself -- because you want the services of someone who knows how to market books.

So if a publisher says your book is in a particular genre, chances are they are right.